# React.js: How to convert class based component to functional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an app using **function based component**. I found the sidebar menu template from **Material Ui** in classes and want to convert it to **functional component**. But after converting **click button** doesn't work. I've only changed the **menu icon** to another.
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the default component in classes

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { NavDrawer } from "./NavDrawer";

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drawerOpened: false
    };
  }
  toggleDrawer = booleanValue => () => {
    this.setState({
      drawerOpened: booleanValue
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="secondary"
              aria-label="Menu"
              onClick={this.toggleDrawer(true)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <NavDrawer
          drawerOpened={this.state.drawerOpened}
          toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar
```

Here I'm trying to convert

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import NavDrawer from './NavDrawer'
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart'

function NavBar(props) {
  const [drawerOpened, setDrawerOpened] = useState(false)

  const toggleDrawer = booleanValue => () => {
    setDrawerOpened(booleanValue)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="AddShoppingCartIcon"
            onClick={() => toggleDrawer(true)}
          >
            <AddShoppingCartIcon style={{ fontSize: 30 }} color="secondary" />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit"></Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <NavDrawer drawerOpened={drawerOpened} toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at React hooks, there ae two approaches:

```
const [toggleDrawer, setToggleDrawer] = useState(false);   // set variable
  <button onClick={() => setToggleDrawer(!toggleDrawer}>
```

Of you can useEffect to perform some logic after the component is initially rendered, preventing a max error:

```
const toggleDrawer = false;

          useEffect(() => {   // update variable
            checkDrawOpened(toggleDrawer)
          }, toggleDrawer);]

With the one click

onClick={toggleDrawer}  // use variable
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Now  "toggleDrawer is not defined", but when I define it, doesn't work

Comment: see updated answer, use useState for a simple switch  Use useEffect to run custom logic to prevent the max eror

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead for toggling actions.

```
const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setDrawerOpened(!drawerOpened)
}
```

And in the return

```
onClick={toggleDrawer}
```

Your function is stacking. On onclick, you try to call function to call function. Just use the const instead.

on toggleDrawer const, you should set setDrawerOpened to whenever the opposite of value it is to get toggling effect.

Comment: thanks for answer, but this couses an error "×
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops"